# What should I install to output HDMI audio on my R9 380?

Tags: linux, audio, hdmi, kernel

I've just installed Debian testing on my new computer with R9 380 display with monitor plugged into HDMI port. However, there is no sound coming out of it, and I found out that amdgpu in the current kernel does not support HDMI audio output.

I further found out that amdgpu-pro supports it but my OS does not support that. I also tried to install the 4.9 and 4.11 packages https://github.com/M-Bab/linux-kernel-amdgpu-binaries , compiled the kernel source with DC on from https://github.com/M-Bab/linux-kernel-amdgpu , and also compiled the kernel source with DC on https://cgit.freedesktop.org/~agd5f/linux/ on amd-staging-4.9 branch, and the result is black screen on all kernels.

What kernel should I install to get back HDMI audio?

Answer (score 0):

this is M-Bab. Basically you went the right way: A kernel with DC/DAL addition is your best chance to get HDMI audio with the open source amdgpu driver.

Do you get ANY feedback from the bootlog/syslog/dmesg? What happens when you try to boot such a kernel?

Did you install my firmware package as well? And did the firmware-amd-graphics package installed in your debian system? The firmware you want with a R9 380 (I got the same GPU) is /lib/firmware/amdgpu/tonga*.bin.

Comment: All those questions should be comments to OPs question, not a part of your answer.